# Error Setting Ratings using SharePoint Client Object Model

Tags: javascript, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-addin, client-object-model

We are attempting to use the example located on this: [Site](http://omicron-llama.co.uk/2013/06/13/setting-page-ratings-using-sharepoint-client-object-model/)

We are receiving the following error: "The assembly Microsoft.SharePoint.Portal.Proxy, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c does not support app authentication"

Another Site that shows a similar example is: [Here](http://blogs.technet.com/b/speschka/archive/2013/07/08/how-to-use-csom-with-ratings-in-sharepoint-2013.aspx) and the only comment lists the same problem we're encountering.

Our App has full trust with the Host Web as we elevated permissions for the app hoping that was the issue.

Comment: Does your page crash? Are you using app model?I using app model make sure in your code the version is 16.0.0.0 and not 15.0.0.0

Comment: Your error message is a bit strange, but the link you provided does not use the [SP.ProxyWebRequestExecutorFactory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj163201(v=office.15).aspx#BasicOps_AccessHostweb) as it should. Have you tried this?

Comment: Thanks @eirikb for your responses. Neither of the suggestions happened to help and unfortunately our contract for this implementation lost funding so at this point in time we've had to move on to other projects. I hope to try and resolve it at a future date.